# Python unittest - division tests into classes/functions

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying learn TDD in python. Unfortunately I have not found any PEPs about unittest.

1. Does one subclass of unittest.TestCase should contain all tests about one tested function?
2. What are the recommendations for naming classes, methods or test-files?

Comment: The documentation has [a bit](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) about that. And I guess the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/test) has some good example for unittests.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make one class that handles the setup and tearing down for a particular test topic and subclass it for every single test. That is, one class for every test, with a name that conveys what is being tested. Nothing fancy.